# Is there any limit on number of parameters that can be passed while startup of any JVM

Tags: performance, jvm, limit, jboss5.x

We are trying to start JBOSS 5.x with JDK 1.6.
Is there any limit on number of parameters that can be passed while startup of any JVM. The parameters are being given with the help of "-Dkey=value" option?
What guides that limit?

Answer (score 1):

The limit is most likely the longest string allowable in a command console that your operation provides. I do not believe that there is any other limit applied.

It is unlikely that you'll hit the limit. Even older systems such as DOS provide an extremely large limit.

http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/faq/command-line/longest.html